# Aviary sdk for ios remove feed back button

Tags: ios

How can I remove feedback button and "powered by aviary" text from my ios app while using aviary sdk,I have searched for solution in aviary documentation,please help.

Answer (score 0):

The feedback button and Aviary branding are a permanent part of the Aviary SDK. Its not possible to remove them.